# WSO2 Data Source: How configure with some users Oracle?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I use WSO2 Data Services and the communication with Oracle is perfect with my main user database.

I created others users with the same profile but with it the WSO2 not communicate. The error message is:

> **Database URL cannot be empty**.

The URL is the same that I use with the main DB user, like this:

> **jdbc:oracle:thin:xxx/xxx@localhost:1521:orcl**

Please, anybody can help-me?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please post your complete datasource configuration so we'll be able to check what's gone wrong.

Comment: Hi Prabath, please, where I can find the the XML with the complete datasource onfiguration? I search in WSO2 DS path, but I don't found.

Comment: If you're using inline datasource configurations in your data service, please refer the following link. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS300/RDBMS

Comment: Or else if you're using "carbon datasources" as your datasource, then refer the link mentioned below.http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS300/Carbon+Data+Sources